# How to move a bucket policy to another CloudFormation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have an S3 bucket with which I want to move from one stack to another one. I was able to move the bucket using the [instructions provided by Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html), however, I wasn't able to move the bucket policy attached to it. What I tried was:

1. Make the bucket and the policy retainable
2. Remove the resources from the origin stack
3. Import the bucket into the target stack (I cannot import Bucket Policy, it's not supported)

After these actions, the bucket has the policy, however, it's not managed by CloudFormation. If I try to add `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy` definition for the bucket to the target stack, the deploy will fail with `The bucket policy already exists on bucket`. I'm looking for a way to overcome this. I understand that I can simply remove the policy using the console and then the error will disappear, but in that case, the resources in the bucket will be unavailable for some time.

The only solution I see is to leave it as-is for production. For other environments (testing, development, etc.) I want CloudFormation to correctly create and remove the bucket and its policy. So the workaround is to define bucket policy for all the environments except production.

Comment: You already answer your question. Only buckets support importing, not bucket policies. If you don't want to touch production now, probably have to wait till some maintenance window.

Comment: Yeah, I hoped there was some trick I'm not aware of. I find it very inconvenient as many use S3 buckets to host static content and those buckets have a "public" policy attached. Just seems to be a common use case.

Comment: An alternative is you could use a lambda to define the [BucketPolicy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-bucket-policies.html) via boto3? Or put a CDN in-front of your static website (like cloudfront) with a cache policy of say an hour, which will give ample time to allow the policy swap in the back-end.